# Prolog, predicate returns the correct result, but also false?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I found that for most of my predicates, prolog finds multiple solutions, with one of them being the correct result, the other is 'false.'

To demontrate:

```
%finds the last element of list, or false if empty.
last([H|L], More):-
    last(L, More).
last([H], H).
```

running this gives:

```
?- last([a, b, c], W).
W = c ;
false.
```

Can anyone explain why it is giving 'false.' in addition? Is this something I need to fix?

Comment: You're hitting `;` thus asking Prolog to try to find more solutions. It can't so it prints `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, nor this is something to fix. What prolog is telling you by printing `false` at the end is that there are no other solutions than the ones it has already shown you. (Note that hitting `;` tells prolog to show you more answers, you can also hit return to simply terminate the query.)

See Section 2.1.3 of https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable/doc/SWI-Prolog-8.2.1.pdf for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify it a bit:

```
last(List, Last):- last(List, _, Last).
last([H | T], _, Last):-
    last(T, H, Last).
last([], Last, Last). % Unify H and Last - no other solution
```

Simple solution:

```
last(List, Last) :-
    once(append(_, [Last], List)).
```